# Aussprache des Wortes »jetzt«

Tags: pronunciation

Eigentlich ist die Aussprache von »jetzt« [jɛtst]. Aber ich will wissen, ob sich die Aussprache dieses Wortes in die Umgangssprache verändert. So steht z.B. [im englischen Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jetzt#German), dass die Aussprache manchmal zu [jɛts] wird.

Comment: Stimmt. 'Jetzt' ist die hochdeutsche, ganz korrekte Form, während im Alltag meist einfach nur 'jetz' gesagt wird, z.B. “Jetz mach doch mal!“.

Comment: Auch wenn es sicher Tendenzen gibt das "t" zu verschlucken, so würde ich darin noch lange keine Entwicklung oder gar Veränderung sehen. Gerade als lauthafte Bekräftigung hat das "t" eine wichtige Bedeutung.

Answer (score 3):

Ja, Wörter werden öfters anders ausgesprochen, als sie geschrieben werden. Statt *jetzt* (mit Schluss-*t)* hört man zum Beispiel oft *jetz* (ohne Schluss-*t),* in Bayern auch oft *jetzat* (mit Schwa-Laut zwischen *tz* und *t).*

Was gesagt wird, hängt davon ab, *wo* im Satz das *jetzt* steht, *wie* schnell oder aufmerksam der Sprecher spricht, zu *welchem Publikum* und *ob* im Dialekt, im stark oder im schwach eingefärbten Hochdeutsch. Dennoch gibt es keinen Sprecher, der nicht auch *jetzt* sagen würde – mindestens in förmlichen Situationen oder wichtigen Reden.

Answer (score 3):

Der Vollständigkeit halber noch eine weitere Variante von "jetzt":

Verschliffen über "jetz" am Satzende zu "jetze" wie in: "Mach doch ma hin jetze!" (= Beeil dich jetzt).

Ort: Berlin, Brandenburg, Sachsen

Answer (score 0):

Ja, du hast recht.

Deutsch war in der Vergangenheit niemals eine einheitliche Sprache, und ist auch heute noch uneinheitlich. Das nennt man eine [plurizentrische Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurizentrische_Sprache).

Das Deutsch, das du gerade als Fremdsprache lernst, ist eine standardisierte Form der deutschen Sprache. Du lernst also eine Sprache, die der Versuch ist, unterschiedliche Dialekte und Umgangssprachen unter einen Hut zu bekommen. Das ist eine Sprache, die jeder versteht, dessen Muttersprache Deutsch ist. Es ist auch die Sprache, in der Zeitungen und Bücher gedruckt wird, und die Nachrichtensprecher in Radio und Fernsehen verwenden. Auch Schauspieler und Politiker sprechen (meistens) in dieser Sprache.

Aber es gibt nur sehr wenige Menschen, für die diese Standardsprache tatsächlich genau mit ihrer Muttersprache übereinstimmt. Fast alle deutschsprachigen Menschen sprechen mit Familienmitgliedern und Freunden einen Dialekt, der von der Standardsprache abweicht, wobei die Abweichung geringfügig, oder auch erheblich sein kann, je nach Region.

Die Folge ist, dass es für fast alle deutschen Wörter mehrere Varianten gibt, wie sie von Muttersprachlern ausgesprochen werden. Es gibt zwischen den Dialekten und der Standardsprache aber noch eine Zwischenschicht, das ist die Umgangssprache. Das ist so etwas wie ein Dialekt, der eine groß geographische Verbreitung hat, und sich nur wenig vom Standard unterscheidet. Das ist die Sprache, mit der z.B. Geschäftsleute mit ihren Kunden sprechen. (Kollegen innerhalb derselben Firma, oder Freunde, sprechen meist einen Dialekt.)

Zu erwähnen ist auch, dass es nicht einmal beim Standard eine echte Vereinheitlichung gibt. Es gibt nämlich drei Variationen des Standards:

- Deutsches Deutsch (ca. 80 Millionen Sprecher)
- Österreichisches Deutsch (ca. 9 Millionen Sprecher)
- Schweizerisches Deutsch (ca. 5 Millionen Sprecher)

Wenn du Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernst, und diesen Unterricht nicht in Österreich oder der der Schweiz besuchst, lernst du deutsches Deutsch.

Comment: Meiner Frage ist nicht die Deutsches Dialekte, aber die Aussprache der Wörter, die in viele Konsonante enden. Erwägt z.B. "trinkst". Sagt man alles 3 Konsonante, wenn man schnell spricht?

Comment: @DHMO: Du wolltest wissen, ob »jetzt« in der Umgangssprache anders ausgesprochen wird als in der Standardsprache. Die Antwort darauf habe ich in meinem ersten Satz gegeben. Sie lautet: »*Ja, du hast recht.*«. Du hast nicht danach gefragt, wie sich die Aussprache in der Umgangssprache  von der Standard-Aussprache unterscheidet. Eine solche Frage ist auch nicht einfach zu beantworten, weil die Umgangssprachen von Hamburg, Berlin, Leibzig, Köln, München, Wien, Zürich usw. sich voneinander deutlich unterscheiden. Es gibt drei sehr ähnliche Standards, hunderte Umgangssprachen und tausende Dialekte.

Comment: Wenn man Standarddeutsch spricht, wird »jetzt« auch dann als [jɛtst] ausgesprochen, wenn man schnell spricht. In gewissen Umgangssprachen wird aber [jɛts] gesagt, selbst dann, wenn man sehr langsam spricht.

Comment: Dialekte gehen noch einen Schritt weiter. In Dialekten verändern sich auch die Grammatik und das Vokabular. Das Wort »jetzt« wird beispielsweise in dem Dialekt, der meine eigentliche Muttersprache ist, durch das Wort »hiaz« ersetzt, das es im Standard gar nicht gibt.

Comment: Und was ist nun mit „jetzt“?

Comment: @CarstenS: Was soll sein? DHMO hat gefragt, ob sich die Aussprache dieses Wortes in der Umgangssprache verändert. Ich habe mit »ja« geantwortet, und habe noch einige Erläuterungen hinzugefügt. Was fehlt dir noch?

Comment: Ok, die erste Zeile hat also tatsächlich mit der Frage zu tun. Großartig. Und du konntest lang und breit darauf hinweisen, dass Deutsch auch in Österreich gesprochen wird und das dort gesprochene (und geschriebene! und beschriebene! und kodifizierte!) Deutsch ebenso ein richtiges Deutsch ist wie das in Deutschland gesprochene. Suuuper. Das hilft ungemein.

Comment: @CarstenS: Fein :) Aber warum fragst du dann »Und was ist nun mit „jetzt“?« Diese Frage klingt so, als würde dir etwas fehlen; als wäre ich darauf nicht eingegangen. Mit deinem letzten (und überflüssigerweise ziemlich zynischen) Kommentar bringst du aber zum Ausdruck, dass ich dir offenbar zu viel geschrieben habe. Bitte entscheide dich: Habe ich deiner Meinung nach zu wenig oder zu viel geschrieben?

Comment: @CarstenS: Ganz allgemein wäre mir aber ohnehin lieber, wenn du dir deine zynischen und sarkastischen, vor allem aber völlig unproduktiven Kommentare sparen würdest. Deine immerfort gleiche Botschaft, dass dir nämlich mein Stil nicht gefällt, ist bei mir schon vor zwei, drei Jahren angekommen. Das weiß ich inzwischen. Bei dir sollte inzwischen aber schön langsam auch etwas ankommen sein, nämlich dass ich meinen Stil wegen dir nicht ändern werde. Du hast ja die Möglichkeit, meine Anworten mit -1 zu bewerten. Davon machst da auch ausgiebig Gebrauch, und das ist auch in Ordnung.

Comment: @CarstenS: Aber gewöhne dir in deinen Kommentaren entweder eine sachlichere Sprache an und poste konstruktive Kritik, oder lass einfach die Finger von der Tastatur!

Comment: Dass Du unbelehrbar bist, ist mir durchaus bewusst. Aber @DHMO wusste Deinen Beitrag vielleicht noch nicht einzuschätzen. Er mag sich gewundert haben, warum Du seitenlang antwortest, obwohl Du nichts beizutragen hast. Der Hinweis, dass das rein ideologisch motiviert ist, war auch für ihn.

Comment: @CarstenS: Inwiefern ideologisch?