# Differences between a Kaufhaus and a Warenhaus

Tags: difference

What are the differences between a Kaufhaus and a Warenhaus?

Do these terms describe **exactly** the same thing?
If not, what are all of the subtle differences?

Also:

- Is a Kaufhaus a kind of Warenhaus?
- Is a Warenhaus a kind of Kaufhaus?
- If none of the above is true, what is the least-general term (so, less general than "Laden" for instance) that encompasses both?

## Research

The German Wikipedia has an article for each, but I haven't been able to grasp the difference:

- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaufhaus
- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warenhaus

Wiktionary also has a different definition for each:

- [Kaufhaus](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kaufhaus): ein Geschäft, wo sich der Verkäufer und die Käufer treffen, um Ware gegen Geld auszutauschen
- [Warenhaus](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Warenhaus): ein Geschäftshaus, Laden, das Güter vieler verschiedener Branchen zum Verkauf anbietet

Dwds too has a different definition for each:

- [Kaufhaus](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kaufhaus): großes, oft mehrstöckiges Geschäft des Einzelhandels für Waren vieler Arten
- [Warenhaus](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Warenhaus): Haus, in dem Waren vieler Branchen im Einzelhandel verkauft werden

Wirtschaftslexikon has different definitions, and a graph with arrows whose meaning is unclear to me:

- [Kaufhaus](http://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/Definition/kaufhaus.html): Betriebsform des Einzelhandels (Betriebsform des Handels); angeboten wird ein sehr tief gegliedertes, branchenhomogenes Sortiment (außer Lebensmitteln) in ausgedehnten Verkaufsräumen. Es gibt sowohl Fachabteilungen mit Beratung als auch Abteilungen mit weit gehender Selbstbedienung. Standort bevorzugt in innerstädtischen Hauptlagen. Verbreitet sind Kaufhäuser für Textilien, Bekleidung, Möbel, Kinderspielzeug.
- [Warenhaus](http://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/Archiv/56445/warenhaus-v4.html): Betriebsform des Handels (Einzelhandel) in zentraler Lage mit branchenübergreifendem, breiten Sortiment einschließlich Lebensmitteln

[image]

Comment: In which context do you need the distinction? Is it for using the terms in colloquial language? Or in business managemt? Or for the historical development of using these terms?

Comment: @IQV: I am interested in exploring both aspects. Should I split my question into a question in the business field, and a question for colloquial language? History is not required.

Comment: I updated my answer and tried to work out both aspects.

Comment: Be aware that both terms, and the businesses they describe, are near outmoded, certainly old-school, and will mean different things to different age groups. Anyone under the age of 40 using "Warenhaus" in a colloquial conversation will probably be assumed to use the term for stylistic reasons. The "SB-Warenhaus" (different business concept again anyway!) is also a very formal term, it would be a Supermarkt to an average German.

Comment: It's the same difference as between a store and a warehouse in English

Comment: Be aware that as an Austrian, the term "Warenhaus" is completely unknown to me, and my first association with it would have been "Lagerhaus", i.e. a storage facility.

Comment: @rackandboneman: What is "near outmoded" about *Kaufhaus* or the business it describes? It is hard to find a larger German city without the omnipresent Kaufhof and/or Karstadt, plus a couple of smaller regional chains.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Sebastian's and your comment imply that an Austrian answer may be warranted. To a German, the English *warehouse* and the German *Warenhaus* are false friends.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ich verstehe nicht ganz was du willst. Ich übersetze deinen ersten Satz als: »Sebastians und dein Kommentar implizieren, dass eine österreichische Antwort garantiert werden kann.« Das ergibt für mich wenig Sinn. Was wolltest du mir sagen?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "is warranted" bedeutet aber nicht nur "ist garantiert", sondern wird auch im Sinn von "ist angebracht/gerechtfertigt" verwendet.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Sorry, ich spreche Englisch nur auf Level B2 oder C1, mache also hin und wieder Fehler. Zur österreichischen Sicht: Eine solche Sicht wurde vom OP nicht verlangt, und ich will mir auch nicht wieder von Carsten irgendwelche beleidigenden Kommentare einfangen, wenn ich ungefragt die Plurizität der deutschen Sprache anspreche. Siehe Carstens Kommentare unter http://german.stackexchange.com/a/35051/1487 Ich hab keinen Bock mehr auf sowas.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't think that the effective non-existence of "Warenhaus" in the Austrian dialects warrants an entire answer, which is why I just posted a comment.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das ist schade, habe ich doch die Beiträge mit (oftmals) deiner österreichischen Perspektive auf die Bedeitung und Verwendung bestimmten Vokabulars meist als sehr informativ bezüglich dieser von mir räumlich gar nicht so unglaublich weit entfernten Sprachvarietät empfunden.

Comment: @SebastianReidl: Fair enough if it's not part of the usual active vocabulary. I just found it noteworthy that both Hubert and you seemed to interpret *Warenhaus* as a storage facility like the English *warehouse*, whereas in Germany, a *Warenhaus* is a type of store where things are sold to consumers - thus making Germans likely to mistranslate *warehouse* as *Kaufhaus* instead of *Lagerhalle*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The false friends have to be seen in historical context. In 18th century a "Warenhaus" was in deed a "warehouse". Only in the course of time you could directly buy offers at the warehouse, so it becomes a store, too.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das sehen aber nicht alle so. Ich habe z.B. in der Antwort, die Carsten kritisiert hat, nicht einmal einen Österreichbezug eingebracht, sondern nur auf die Uneinheitlichkeit der deutschen Sprache hingewiesen, was offenbar schon zu viel ist, und mir als "ideologisch motiviert" angelastet wurde.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Zur vorliegenden Frage könnte ich ohnehin nur beitragen, dass "Warenhaus" in Österreich ungebräuchlich ist (Kaufhaus übrigens auch, aber das ist doch noch einigermaßen bekannt). Ich lernte das englische Wort "warehouse" vor dem deutschen "Warenhaus" kennen, und zwar in "Datawarehouse". Daraus habe ich abgeleitet, dass ein *warehouse* so etwas wie eine Lagerhalle sein muss, von der aus die Geschäfte (*stores*) einer Handelskette beliefert werden, und habe diese Bedeutung auf das mir eigentlich unbekannte deutsche Wort *Warenhaus* übertragen.

Comment: (Forts.) In Österreich kauft man in *Geschäften* ein. Nur sehr große mehrstöckige Geschäfte mit einem sehr breiten Warenangebot werden *Kaufhaus* genannt, z.B. Gerngross in Wien oder Kastner&Öhler in Graz. Raiffeisen betreibt in Österreich neben Banken und landwirtschaftlichen Agrargenossenschaften auch eine Einzelhandelskette, die den Namen »*Lagerhaus*« trägt. Diese Lagerhäuser gibt nur in ländlichen Gebieten, und sie sind eine Mischung aus Baumarkt und Lebensmittelgeschäft, also Geschäfte, in denen Landwirte (fast) ihren ganzen Bedarf decken können. Aber *Warenhäuser* gibt es in Ö keine.

Answer (score 8):

For most Germans there would be no difference in meaning. You would use whichever term is used by the place itself. Also there might be some regional preferences. As for me, I would tend to rather use "Kaufhaus" than "Warenhaus".

And in most situations you would rather refer to it by the company name: "Ich gehe zu Karstadt."

However in economics/management these terms have a distinct meaning.

[Warenhaus](http://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/Archiv/56445/warenhaus-v4.html) has a wider range of products **including food** compared to a [Kaufhaus](http://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/Definition/kaufhaus.html). So technically there is a difference.

Apparently this distinction is not followed strictly in reality (as you can see in case of the KaDeWe which does sell food).

Comment: Thanks for uncovering several aspects of the question! So, if you were teletransported to such a store in an unknown location, with all brand names hidden, without being able to ask the locals, your only way to know what the locals are calling it would be to see whether they have food or not, and even then you would have a chance to get it wrong. Did I understand correctly? Thanks :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul What I mean is that outside of people in economics/management the terms are used interchangeably whether they have food or not. If I was teletransported to such a place I would use "Kaufhaus" (for reasons unknown to me) and I would not even check whether they have food or not, because I would not know it made a difference.

Comment: I see! I would be very interested in knowing how people in the economics/management field describe the difference. This would be a good complement to the explanation above of how non-specialists describe the difference.

Comment: Coming from the Northwest, I've never heard the term "Warenhaus" be used.

Answer (score 2):

In **colloquial** usage there is no difference between these two terms. People usally will use it as synomyms.

Only in **technical** terms esp. in business management there are differences. The main difference - as pointed out in the Wikipedia-article "Warenhaus" - is that a Warenhaus offers foods and a "Kaufhaus" not.
Furthermore a shop is defined to be a "Kaufhaus" if it has at minimum 1.000 m<sup>2</sup> selling area. On the other hand a "Warenhaus" needs at minimum 3.000 m<sup>2</sup> selling area.
Then a "Kaufhaus" offers goods of one (or only few) groups of goods, e.g. textiles or electronics. A "Warenhaus" offers goods of any kind.
So, in technical terms a "Warenhaus" also is a "Kaufhaus" as it offers goods, but offers more than a "Kaufhaus".

But in real life you can't rely on these distinctions. For example the famous "KaDeWe" (*Kaufhaus* des Westens) in Berlin is technically a *Warenhaus* as it has a big department with foods. So beside the theory in business management you will find a "Kaufhaus" which offers foods as you can find a "Warenhaus" without it.

Comment: To make things clearer: Do ALL Warenhaus offer food? Also, do Kaufhaus NEVER offer food? Response to these two questions will help me understand which one is a subset of the other, or whether none is a subset of the other. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

The terms mean pretty much the same. The difference (selling food) mentioned in the other answers is taken from a professional reference. Since I never encountered it before, I assume it't not exactly well-established elsewhere. So I would summarize the first sentence of CarstenS link: Colloquially used synonymously.

The next time you could try a dictionary instead of a encyclopedia, like [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kaufhaus) or [Dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kaufhaus). Less information means less work to extract the essence.

Comment: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaufhaus#Abgrenzung

Comment: "*pretty much the same*": Please be explicit and write "exactly the same", or describe the subtle differences. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Kaufhaus: Retail. Shopping center.
Warenhaus: Warehouse. Wholesale. Wholesale outlet, but usually more for trade among merchants rather than to individuals.

http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Warenhaus

I have never seen "Warenhaus" used to indicate mass-retail shopping outlets. dict.leo.org is your friend.

If you wish to indicate retail then Kaufhaus. Lookslike Warenhaus works both for wholesale and retail. Grosshandel is exclusively wholesale.

Comment: I was so confused why nobody mentioned this. I've never seen Warenhaus used in a retail setting.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrum_Warenhaus